SSIS package with Oracle connections fails running from SQL Job but works from Integration Server
I have developed a SSIS package that uses an Oracle connection.
It works if I run from Visual Studio 2022 and also if I execute the package in the Integration Services Server (Both options at SQL Server machine).
I have created a SQL Job to schedule the execution of this package and I get this error:

Failed to acquire connection "ORACLE_CONNECTION". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on
this connection.

I run the job step as a proxy with the same credentials as Integration Service run.
As far I know both Visual Studio 2022 and Integration Service runs in 64 bit, but just in case I have also tried to set the Use 32 bit runtime option in step execution options but I got the same error.
Thanks in advance.

(1) No need in 32-bit, just 64-bit edition, (2) I hope Oracle Client is not installed, (3) It is better to use EzConnect format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver16

I installed the Oracle Connector but, if I am not wrong, it only allows me to add an Oracle source/Oracle destination in a Data Flow Task. I cannot select this Oracle connection in a Execute SQL Task, which is what I want.
As I say, my package runs properly when I do it from de SSIS catalog or from Visual Studio, I don't understand why it doesn't work in a SQL job...

"...I cannot select this Oracle connection in a Execute SQL Task, which is what I want...." It is a limitation of the current version. A usual workaround is to create a linked server to Oracle db on any SQL Server instance. After that EXECUTE (...) AT [linked server] is working well.

I have included the Oracle bin path (in my case C:\Oracle\X64\bin\) in the Path Environment variable and everything works.
